# How should this instanceof condition look like?

Tags: java

I have a list of nodes. This nodes are a data class I defined by myself. Each node has a data field of the type Object. Now I want to find the node in a list of nodes that has the parameter object in the data field. I wrote this method, because I wanted to first compare if the two objects (the parameter and the object in the data field) are of the same type:

```
public Node getnNodeByData(Object obj) {
    for (Node node : nodes) {
        if (node.getData() instanceof obj.getClass()) {

        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately this condition does not work:

```
Incompatible operand types boolean and Class<capture#1-of ? extends Graph>
```

I don't really know why this is a problem. How can I make this working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you need to use [`Class.isInstance(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance%28java.lang.Object%29).  The `instanceof` keyword does not expect an object of type `Class`, but only the name of the class directly -- but `Class.isInstance` is basically analogous.

Answer (score 3):

No, that is not possible like that. You should use [`isAssignableFrom()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom%28java.lang.Class%29) or [`isInstance()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance%28java.lang.Object%29). The difference between the two methods is that `isInstance(null)` will return false and `isAssignableFrom(null)` will give true.

---

```
[object] instanceof [class]
```

should be translated to this:

```
[class].class.isAssignableFrom(object.getClass());
```

Example:

```
Integer i = 4;
boolean b = i instanceof Number;
boolean k = Number.class.isAssignableFrom(i.getClass());
```

b and k are equivalent.